# How to i use the Template for the Journal of Environmental Radioactivity?

Tags: templates, journal

I am trying to write an article for the Journal of Environmental Radioactivity on Latex, using the template avaible on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/ , but there are so many .tex files, and none seems to work, i couldn't find any guides that work. I am familiar with the use o Latex but this one got me hard.

Please help!

Comment: They have a pretty clear description here: https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!